# Custom Clickstart with Templates and Github

Tags: cloudbees

We are using Cloudbees dev@cloud service, and are looking to create a number of application based off of an archetype stored in Github. I would like to create a custom ClickStart in order to streamline the process.

We are currently forking the archetype, then using a Folder Template that I have created to provision a build pipeline for the application.

While I have been able to create a simple ClickStart, I would like to create one that:

Forks or copies the clickstart source into a Github repository, and not cloudbees forge. The GitHub API supports this.

Point to my folder template using the Jenkins XML API. Currently, not all attributes of a folder template are represented in the rendered XML.

Target a specific folder to create my new folder job under.

The ClickStart API and JSON doesn't seem that well documented, and I have gotten about as far as I can go with trial-and-error.

Is what I am looking to accomplish possible with the current state of the Clickstart API?

Answer (score 1):

> Forks or copies the clickstart source into a Github repository

I do not believe this is possible today. Certainly it has been proposed.

> not all attributes of a folder template are represented in the rendered XML

Such as what? The `config.xml` of a folder, just like that of a job, should be definitive. (It does not include definitions of *child* items.)

> Target a specific folder

Also not possible today that I know of. (Though the user of the ClickStart could always move the result into a subfolder after the fact.)

Comment: I have tried to retrieve the xml using the /api/xml suffix, but the tasks to create items are not rendered, and the job attributes are rendered but the nodes contain no information. Give it a try with a folder template.

Comment: Do not confuse `$itemurl/api/xml` with `$itemurl/config.xml`. These are distinct REST endpoints with distinct purposes.

Comment: Thanks, Jesse. I didn't realize that there were separate endpoints.